# Import some database entries through PHPMyAdmin with overwrite

Tags: mysql, database, import, phpmyadmin, export

I exported a couple of entries from a database I have stored locally on my MySQL dbase through PhpMyAdmin and I'd like to replace only those entries on my destination database hosted online. Unfortunately when I try to do so PHPMyAdmin says that those posts already exist and therefore he can't erase them.

It'll take me a lot of time to search for those entries manually within the rest of the posts and delete them one at a time so I was wondering if there's any workaround in order to overwite those entries on import.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit your question and share your exported and to be exported entires (just few raw/genuine entries) on sqlfiddle and give link here. Then get your result in few minutes :)

Comment: Seems you have a primary key which restricts same entries duplication. If this is the case, You can have solution through stored procedure if you are interested. How? Selecting record from one table and inserting rows one by one through loop,  using continue handler for 1062 where duplication

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A great option is to handle this on your initial export from phpMyAdmin locally. When exporting from phpMyAdmin:

1. Export method: Custom
2. Format: SQL
3. Format-specific options - choose "data" (instead of "structure" or "structure and data")
4. In Data creation options - Function to use when dumping data: Switch "Insert" to "Update" <-- This is the ticket!
5. Click Go!

Import into your production database. (always backup your production database before hand just in case)

I know this is an old post, but it actually helped me find a solution built into phpMyAdmin. Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks, exactly what I was looking for :D

Answer (score 5):

This is a quick and dirty way to do it.  Others may have a better solution:

It sounds like you're trying to run INSERT queries, and phpMyAdmin is telling you they already exist.  If you use UPDATE queries, you could update the info.

I would copy the queries you have there, into a text editor, preferably one that can handle find and replace, like Notepad++ or Gedit, and then replace some code to change the queries around from INSERT to UPDATE.

See:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

OR, you could just delete them, then run your INSERT queries.

You might be able to use some logic with find and replace to make a DELETE query that gets rid of them first.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: Thanks, I had lost the reference of the exported posts because I mass deleted a column across all rows so I went back to a previous backup, deleted the entries whose column data I needed to keep and only then I erased the data from the rest, afterwards I imported the first ones with data back into place.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [insert on duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). You can either add the syntax to your entries stored locally, or import into a temporary database, then run an `INSERT ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. If you could post a schema, it would help us guide you better.